# $\angle BAC=20^{\circ}, \angle BDA=70^{\circ}, \angle BCA=35^{\circ}, \angle BDC=40^{\circ}$. Then : $\angle AOD=?$

Tags: calculus, geometry

The quadrilateral $ABCD$, $AC\cap BD=\left \{ O \right \}$; $\angle BAC=20^{\circ}, \angle BDA=70^{\circ}, \angle BCA=35^{\circ}, \angle BDC=40^{\circ}$.

> Then : $\angle AOD=?$

Thanks ! :)

P/s : I truly have no ideas about this problem !! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k(X,r)$ be a circumscribed circle of triangle $ABC$.
Notice that for angles on tetive $AB$ (analogously for tetive $BC$) holds: $$70^{o}=\measuredangle ADB=2 \measuredangle ACB=2\cdot 35^{o}.$$
Since measure of central angle is twice the measure of peripheral angle (here: $\measuredangle ADB=2 \measuredangle ACB$; same for angles over tetive $BC$), we can conclude that $D$ is a center of circle $k$, from where follows $X\equiv D$.

In triangle $ABD$ is $AD=BD=r$ and $\measuredangle DAB=\measuredangle DBA$, therefore 
$$\measuredangle DAB+\measuredangle DBA=180^{o}-\measuredangle ADB=110^{o},$$
$$\measuredangle DAB=\measuredangle DBA=55^{o}.$$
Also,
$$\measuredangle DAO=\measuredangle DAB-\measuredangle OAB=55^{o}-20^{o}=35^{o}.$$
Finally,
$$\measuredangle AOD=180^{o}-\measuredangle DAO-\measuredangle ODA,$$
$$\measuredangle AOD=180^{o}-35^{o}-70^{o},$$
$$\measuredangle AOD=75^{o}.$$

Comment: So $\angle BDC=40^o$ is useless @@!?

Comment: No, we used that to conclude that D is center of circumscribed circle.

Comment: How did we used it @@!??

Comment: More precisely: from $40^{o}=\measuredangle BDC=2\measuredangle BAC=2\cdot20^{o}$ and $70^{o}=\measuredangle ADB=2\measuredangle ACB=2\cdot 35^{o}$, we got that $DB$ is half diameter ($BD=r$) and since $B\in k(X,r)$, we had $D\equiv X$.